# Retrieving 'Likes' programmatically

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

I am doing an analysis of Credit Union social activity.  I have some code that takes a link like this...

https://www.facebook.com/americanlakecu/likes

... and converts it to this...

http://graph.facebook.com/americanlakecu

..which enables me to grab 'Likes' and 'People Talking'.  The problem is many institutions, particularly the smaller ones, seem to use a different format.  Here's an example.

https://www.facebook.com/pages/EvergreenDIRECT-Credit-Union/276887662722?sk=likes

Anyone know how to convert the link above so I can use the api to render JASON in the same way as http://graph.facebook.com/americanlakecu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the facebook id when hitting the graph for the other institutions.  For americanlakecu, that id is americanlakecu.  For Evergreen's case, try 276887662722.  But for some reason, your "smaller" pages need an access token.  I think the difference might be a simple matter of availability of data.

You can still get their data as I described above, but you need an api access token.  For instance, following this link directly will show you nothing: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=276887662722 , but after you get there, if you fetch an access token, you will see all the info you need.

So, configure your implementation of the SDK to use an access token, and you ought to be able to continue using the handy graph method.

Comment: Thanks Seth.  I was able to get data via the explorer per your suggestion. Now I need to figue out how to go through these steps programmatically using PHP so I can write 'likes' to my database... Seems overly complex, but it's encouraging to know it's possible.

Comment: Ok... this seem inconstant.  Why do some need an Access token, while others do not.  If somebody know, please share.  But this works...https://graph.facebook.com/276887662722/?access_token=xxxx

Comment: I tried to figure that out with your two examples, but I couldn't find anything specific that was different.  I had to just assume that the two apps had different permission settings, but I couldn't verify it.